# Python3.8.3でpandasが使えない

Tags: python, python3, pandas

現在VScodeで作業をしているのですが、pandasライブラリがPython3.8.8では使えるのに対し、3.8.3の環境では使えず困っています。ライブラリのインストールはpipコマンドで行いました。

自分なりに調べましたが、pandasのバージョンを変更すべきか再インストールすべきかも分かりませんでした。対処法を教えていただけると幸いです。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Import "pandas" could not be resolved from source
```

Comment: この辺の記事が何か参考になるかも。[pandasエラーの解決方法](https://teratail.com/questions/359291), [Import \[Module\] could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68638109/9014308)

Comment: 3.8.3の不具合を修正したのが3.8.8になります。
3.8.8で動くのなら問題ないと思いますが。
3.8.3をどうしても使いたい理由があるのですか？

Comment: ありがとうございました！